# silent apple push notification with sns topic and boto3

Tags: ios, python-2.7, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns, boto3

```
topic = sns.Topic(topic_arn)
body = {'aps': {'content-available': 1, 'sound': ''}, 'update_type': 2, 'update_code': 44584}
body_json = json.dumps(body, ensure_ascii=False)

message = {'default': 'The default message',
           'APNS_SANDBOX': body_json}

MESSAGE_JSON = json.dumps(message, ensure_ascii=False)

response = topic.publish(
    Message=MESSAGE_JSON,
    Subject='test subject',
    MessageStructure='json'
)
```

This is how I tried to publish a message to topic with `sns` and `boto3`. It is working fine and I get a notification in my `iOS` mobile like

```
{
   "aps" =     {
       "alert" = {
                  "default" = "The default message";
                  "APNS_SANDBOX" = {
                                   "aps" = {
                                            "content-available" = 1;
                                            "sound" = ""
                                    };
                                    "update_type" = 2;
                                    "update_code" = 44584;
                                   }
                 }
               }
}
```

As per my knowledge, because of the message I send coming under "alert" tag, it immediately displays in the notification area even the app is not working in the background.

Many links, suggest to append **"content-available": 1**, yet the result is not changed.
Actually, I am looking for a silent push notification so that I can take some action based on that. for that, I have to get the notification like

```
{
  aps =     {
      "content-available" = 1;
      "sound" = "";
  };
  "update_code" = 44584;
  "update_type" = 2;
}
```

Why **alert** tag is coming in the notification even I include **"content-available": 1**?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Remove the `sound` entry

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be related to my same problem that I never solved:

[Silent push](https://gist.github.com/tmarshall/6149ed2475f964cda3f5)